# Applying third-party themes to Qt Creator

Tags: themes, qt-creator

I downloaded Qt Creator and I want to set the [Dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/qtcreator/) for it.

It is instructed that third party themes are to be put in `$HOME\.config\QtProject\qtcreator\styles` (Windows). Fine, but after I've copied the file into that folder, the theme is not showing up in the theme list, when I'm trying to set a new theme in Qt Creator, selecting *Tools > Options > Text Editor > Theme-button*.

I'm quite (90%) sure the path/location is correct, but I assume the themes have moved to somewhere else.

How do I set up this theme, instead of the default dark-theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The themes were moved to `PathToQt\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\styles`, where the `.xml` file is to be placed.

Comment: For macOS, path is `/Applications/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/styles` for Qt Creator 4.14

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text editor theme, the path is still `$HOME.config\QtProject\qtcreator\styles` (at least on MacOS) but you will find the added styles in parameters / Text Editor / Font & Colors : Color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

1. Move the `dracula.xml` file to `C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\styles`.
2. Move the `drakula.creatortheme` file to `C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\themes`.
3. Go to *Qt Creator -> <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd>*, click the <kbd>Environment</kbd> tab, and select <kbd>Drakula</kbd> in the <kbd>Theme</kbd>. Then click <kbd>Restart Now</kbd> in the dialog that will pop up.
4. Go to *Qt Creator -> <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd>*, click the <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> tab, and select <kbd>Dracula</kbd> in the <kbd>Color Scheme</kbd>.

Step 4 is not necessary, Qt Creator will automatically change the text editor's color scheme if it detects it's available.

**Note:** There are no `styles` and `themes` folders by default, they must be created.

[image]